# accessing a machine locally without network auth?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, security, authentication

I have a machine that probably used LDAP or something for auth on a network but im trying to login to manage the system but cant seem to login even after doing a reset of the administrator password. ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to log on as `<hostname>\Administrator` to do a local login. The hostname will probably be displayed on the login dialog, or is choosable using a dropdown list.